# Add image button to gridview databound dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview

I am displaying a gridview which should display a column containing image button.

How can I add image button to gridview row dynamically?

I don't want to enter by using template field from design field of the gridview. As this is image button I should be able to capture the event of the same.How to do the same?

Comment: Check this link,it might help you. http://forums.asp.net/t/1169201.aspx/1

Comment: check out this
[adding Dynamic controls](http://10stupidthings.wordpress.com/2007/07/18/gridview-and-dynamic-controls/)

Comment: thanks that worked!! i could see the image button now!!
But how can i add the click event of the image button???

Comment: you can use this to add the event `img.Click += new EventHandler(img_Click);

 }
 
void img_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 Label1.Text = "Text set from dynamic button Click event";
 }

Comment: Also, if you want to add the onclick event (javascript) to the image button you can do this: img.Attributes.Add("onclick","yourjavascriptfunctionHere();"); and obvioulsy, you need to define yourjavascriptfunctionHere() in your aspx page.

Comment: @Ashley: The event that you have written doesn't works. It threws an error of "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.EventHandler' to 'System.Web.UI.imageclickeventhandler'. I have created an event with argument as EventArgs as mentioned by you

Answer (score 1):

i think you can add image to your edit and delete buttons from .aspx file also, i just tried and got it..
1.firstly make the gridview and then add activities like `OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting"`

i ma showing you jow to add images to edit and delete button for "update" and "cancel" you can proceed in the same way..

now go to source of gridview..

you will see code like this

```
 <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True"/>
 <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True"/>
```

after that change few things like add

```
 <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ButtonType="Image" EditImageUrl="~/uploads/edit.png" />
 <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ButtonType="Image" DeleteImageUrl="~/uploads/delete.png" />
```

And after that make sure to save your images in 45 * 25 sizes only , and save it in any folder and remember to specify the path as i have done here , my folder is uploads.

Note: don't store images in App_data , it is for storing .mdf database files , any images will not work for you.. if the images is not showing in drop down list while adding imageurl try to add its path physically.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use template field for this. What you have to do is at the GridView RowDataBound event find the ImageButton you added in the template field and then give an ID or Row number or something which you can use to identify which row the ImageButton is in, as an Attribute of the ImageButton.

You can use this place to give the ImageUrl as well a sample would look like the below one.

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            ImageButton imgbtn = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("imgbtn1");
            if (imgbtn != null)
            {
                imgbtn.Attributes["id"] = e.Row.RowIndex.ToString();
            }

        }
    }
```

then you can create the click event for ImageButton. In that you can get the id/rowindex of the image button which was clicked and do what ever you want. Event may look like the below

```
 protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)sender;
        string rowindex = btn.Attributes["id"];

    }
```

then in the GridView template field you can add the click event to ImageButtons onClick event. This may look like the below

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton  runat ="server" ID="imgbtn1"  onclick="ImageButton1_Click"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```